# Include directional keys on Soft Keyboard

Tags: android

I'm using `EditText`'s with the xml code:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

which filters the keyboard to only 0123456789. Thats fine.

**My problem:** I want to add the directional/arrow keys  **<--** , **-->** that moves the cursor, to this keyboard. Or another method that leads to the same result.
Had already searched but no luck...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you writing your *own* input method editor (soft keyboard), and are asking how to add arrow keys to it?

Comment: I know I can also use android:digits:"0123456789."  . I was wondering if i could add the arrow keys to it...But idk if thats possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText. SetSelection(position);
```

**Call this function to set cursor position after finding entered string length in EditText. setTextWatcher()**

AND search on google to create custom keyboard in android